# Close WPF dialog without user interaction

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog

I would like to show dialog during some IO operations and after it, close the dialog with code.
Something like:

```
DialogWindow dialog = new DialogWindow();
dialog.ShowDialog();
.... do some file operation....
dialog.Close();
```

but dialog won't close. I have to close it by myself. Is here way how to close it with code?

Answer (score 3):

```
DialogWindow dialog = new DialogWindow();
Task.Run(()=>
{
    .... do some file operation....
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)dialog.Close);
});
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .Show(), not ShowDialog(). If you use ShowDialog, the new window is modal, so you must close manually the window, before you can reach the line of codice dialog.Close().

Comment: I tried to use `.Show()`, but it that case, user can work with parent window, and i don't want to allow it.

Comment: another solution: you can use ShowDialog, but you must call .Close from the modal window (the new instance of DialogWindow), with this.Close().

Comment: If I create new method `CloseThisWindow()` (inside is `this.Close()`) and call this method, I still have to close dialog manually.

Comment: Try to see this little example : https://1drv.ms/u/s!AulV5ZgqqfHGjrcDb5HBiGaHvjco0w - I just write it in WPF. After 3 seconds, the DialogWindow automatically close itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use ShowDialog() because it blocks the current thread.

You could disable the owner window while the process is running and then enable it afterwards like this ('this' is the owner window) (you'll have to be carefull with errors and exceptions, of course):

```
    async private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Window1 win = new Window1();
  this.IsEnabled = false;
  win.Show();
  await Task.Run(() =>
    {
      Thread.Sleep(2000);
    });

  win.Close();
  this.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

An alternative is to run the file operation in the opened dialog (opened with ShowDialog() then) instead of in the main window.

Answer (score 0):

If using ShowDialog() then can use below code to close dialog.

(this.Parent as Window).Close();